# Selenium WebDriver fails to capture error message of gmail login

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gmail, automated-tests

I am trying to capture the error message on gmail login If I do not populate the user name and click on Next button, then "Please enter your email" message appears, but Selenium gives the error message- argument is not found.
My code is:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class Msg 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();   
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']")).click();
              Thread.sleep(2000);   
    WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']"));
    String js="argument[0].style.height='auto';     argument[0].style.visibility='visible';";
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(js,ele);

    String actual=ele.getText();
    System.out.println(actual);
    //String expected= "Please enter your email";
    Assert.assertEquals(actual, "Please enter your email");
    System.out.println("Pass");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.testng.Assert;

    public class Msg 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\LMS_Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();   
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']")).click();
              Thread.sleep(2000);   
    WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']"));
    WebElement error=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='error-msg']"));
    String actual=error.getText();
    System.out.println(actual);
    //String expected= "Please enter your email";
    Assert.assertEquals(actual, "Please enter your email.");
    System.out.println("Pass");
    }
    }
```